# Pourquoi certains prénoms sont-ils au pluriel ?

Tags: noms-propres, prénoms

Pourquoi ces prénoms sont-ils au pluriel : Jules, Charles, Georges ? Y en a-t-il d'autres ?

Comment: Ces prénoms ne sont pas au pluriel, il se trouve qu'ils s'écrivent avec un s parce qu'ils dérivent de prénoms latins qui s'écrivaient avec un s. Jules du latin *Julius*, Georges du latin *Georgius* (lui-même du grec *Geōrgios*). Pour Charles la dérivation est moins directe puisque le prénom vient du germanique *Karl* qui a été latinisé en *Karolus*.

Comment: Pour illustrer l'example d'un mot courant utilisé en français : « un corps » de « corpus ». Ici, pareil avec certains prénoms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ces prénoms ne sont pas au pluriel. Le « s » final est ici un héritage du nominatif masculin singulier latin:

- Julius -> Jules
- Karolus -> Charles
- Georgius -> Georges

Comme autre prénom de ce style, on trouve au moins Marius.

Il existe de nombreux autres prénoms français ayant une terminaison en « s ». Ils sont d'origines variées:

- Anaïs
- Clovis
- Colas
- Denis
- Eudes
- François
- Hugues
- Inès
- Louis
- Lucas
- Nicolas
- Régis
- Stanislas
- Thomas
- Yves

Comment: J'ai une question : comment vous avez fait pour trouver cette liste de noms ?

Comment: @OSryx Quelque chose comme ça: `wget -q -O - http://fr.wikimini.org/wiki/Liste_des_pr%C3%A9noms_en_fran%C3%A7ais | awk '/<li.*href=/ { gsub("</a> *$","") ; gsub(".*>",""); if ( $0 ~ "s$") print }'`